# Redirect/Rewrite (in nginx) Requests to Subdirectory to S3-Compatible Bucket

Tags: nginx, redirect, amazon-s3, url-rewriting

I am attempting to get nginx to redirect/rewrite requests to a specific subdirectory so that they are served by an S3-compatible bucket instead of the server. Here is my current server block:

`{snip}` (See *infra*.)

Despite fiddling with this for some time now, I've only been able to get it to return 404s.

### Additional Information

https://omnifora.com/t/redirect-rewrite-in-nginx-requests-to-subdirectory-to-s3-compatible-bucket/402

### Attempts Solutions So Far

1. `rewrite`

   rewrite ^/security-now/(.*) $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/bits-podcasts/security-now/$1;
2. `return`

   return 302 $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/bits-podcasts/security-now/$1;
3. `proxy_pass`

   proxy_set_header Host s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com;
           proxy_pass $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/bits-podcasts/security-now/$1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `rewrite` for cross-domain redirections, for this case you must use `proxy_pass`, for example:

```
    location ~ ^/directory1/(.*) {
        proxy_set_header Host s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com;
        proxy_pass $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/target-bucket/security-now/$1;
    }
```

Note that if you specify your server with domain name instead or IP address, you'll need to specify additional parameter [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) in your `server` configuration block, for example:

```
server {
    ...
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    ...
}
```

---

Update.

It seems I was wrong stating that you can't use `rewrite` for cross-domain redirections. You can, but in this case your user got HTTP 301 redirect instead of "transparent" content delivery. Maybe you got 404 error because you missed a $ sign before `scheme` variable?

Comment: I tried both correcting the omission of the `$` and the following without success:

```server {
    resolver 1.1.1.1;

    location  ~ ^/directory1/(.*) {
        proxy_set_header Host s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com;
        proxy_pass $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/target-bucket/security-now/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this configuration on my server, and it seems to work.
Are other requests to your server processed successfully?

Comment: It appears to be serving all other requests properly. Just this redirect/rewrite isn't working. I also tried:

`return 302 $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/target-bucket/security-now/$1;`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think all `server` blocks must have a `server_name` parameter. You can use `server_name _;`, it will be used for all server names that not matched with other blocks, so if you have only one `server` block in your configuration, it will work like a wildcard.

Comment: I added a `server_name` parameter and tried `rewrite`, `return`, and `proxy_pass`, but they all still return 404s.

Comment: For the sake of clarity (and because I don't really care about 'masking' any of the actual information involved), here's a link to the full config for that site and the exact code I've been attempting to get working: https://omnifora.com/t/redirect-rewrite-in-nginx-requests-to-subdirectory-to-s3-compatible-bucket/402?u=mahler

Comment: First of all, move
`resolver 1.1.1.1; location ~ ^/security-now/(.*) { proxy_set_header Host 3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com; proxy_pass $scheme://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/bits-podcasts/security-now/$1; }` into your first `server` block, with `listen 443 ssl` parameter, under the first `location` directive.
Secondly, I just tried to change resolver from `8.8.8.8` to `1.1.1.1` in my config, and got a 502 error. I don't know why is it happen, but it seems that nginx is incompatible with this name server. Try `8.8.8.8` if you'll get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184496/discussion-between-ivan-shatsky-and-zyniker).

Answer (score 0):

Worked here with `resolver 8.8.8.8` and `server_name _`